# Do I need to specify certificate authority when using pdo in php to connect mysql server over tls?

Tags: php, mysql, ssl

We enabled ssl on mysql server with self-signed certificates and require ssluser to use ssl. So I cant connect with options below;

```
mysql -u ssluser -p
```

but I can connect with options below;

```
mysql -u ssluser -p --ssl=1
```

And while connecting I don't need to specify CA certificates created for client side.

I am connecting to mysql server with options below;

```
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => true,
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
```

But I don't specify any files. Does mysql works like a webserver and sends to the client the public key? Or are my settings are wrong?

I am using mysql 8.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connections seem to be fine. You can verify this on the `mysql` command line by issuing the `status` command and looking for the SSL line.

MySQL does indeed work like a webserver. Your configuration does not require your client to present a certificate.

Web servers can require browsers to present client certificates, but most don't. Similarly, the MySQL server can require clients to present client certificates, but yours doesn't.

You are good to go, I believe.